# Retrieve data from a certain column and i can change the image whenever the data is different

Tags: php, sql, image

Is it possible to retrieve data from a certain column and have a if else statement to it where i can change the image?
So basically i want to the pic to tally with the location that i retrieve with the database.

```
<?php

$servername = "......byethost5.com";
$username = "....";
$password = "...";
$dbname = "b...";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Location,DateTime FROM SensorDetails LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Last Seen Location: " . $row["Location"]."<br>";
                 $Help= $row["Location"];
            if($Help=='Toilet')
             {echo '<center><img src="Toilet.jpg"></center>';}
            elseif($Help=='Kitchen')
              {echo '<center><img src="Kitchen.jpg</center>';}
            else {echo '<center><img src="BedRoom.jpg"></center>';}


    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is use the same name for 'Location' field and its current image.

```
<?php    
    $servername = "......byethost5.com";
    $username = "....";
    $password = "...";
    $dbname = "b...";


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Image folder
    //put here the folder where you save images
    $img_folder = './'; //current folder
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT Location,DateTime FROM SensorDetails LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $img_file = $img_folder . $row["Location"] . '.jpg';  
            //echo $img_file; //uncomment this if you wanna check img's path.
            if( ! file_exists($img_file) ){//Check if the file exists
                $img_file = '';         
            }                       
            echo "Last Seen Location: " . $row["Location"]."<br>";
        echo "<center><img src="$img_file"></center>";

     }                      
    }else {
    echo "<p> 0 results </p>";
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

This solution is more appropriate if you're going to have more locations in the future. I supposed that you keep the images in the same folder as this script and all the images are in JPG format.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to store the Image URL (or last part) in the database as a separated column, and echo the image same you echo the field location.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can display different images for different locations .

I have considered your code and modified it a little bit .

```
if( $result->num_rows > 0 )
{
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc( ) )
    {
        echo 'Last Seen Location: ' .$row[ 'Location' ] .'<br>';

        $location = trim( $row[ 'Location' ] ); // trim to make sure no spaces on either side

        switch( strtolower( $location ) )
        {
            case 'toilet'   : $image = 'Toilet.jpg';    break;
            case 'kitchen'  : $image = 'Kitchen.jpg';   break;
            case 'bedroom'  : $image = 'BedRoom.jpg';   break;
            default         : $image = 'BedRoom.jpg';   // Change default image as needed
        }
        echo '<center><img src="' .$image .'"></center>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Notes :
I have used [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) instead of [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) .
I have used [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) on `$location` before comparing .
I have renamed `$Help` to `$location` for readability .